# Could not resolve entry module "src/config/axios-interceptor.ts/index.html"

Tags: reactjs, vite

I need help with my ReactJS Typescript project using Vite. It runs fine with npm run build, but I get an error 'Could not resolve entry module "src/config/axios-interceptor.ts/index.html".' when I commit and run lint-staged.

```
 npm run build

> @devias-kit-pro/vite-starter@6.4.2 build
> tsc && vite build

vite v4.4.0 building for production...
✓ 2247 modules transformed.
dist/index.html                                                        1.10 kB │ gzip:   0.48 kB
dist/assets/slick-12459f22.svg                                         2.15 kB │ gzip:   0.92 kB
dist/assets/roboto-mono-vietnamese-300-normal-bd7de91e.woff2           4.10 kB
dist/assets/ajax-loader-e7b44c86.gif                                   4.18 kB
dist/assets/inter-greek-ext-400-normal-d3e30cde.woff2                  4.76 kB
...
dist/assets/inter-latin-ext-800-normal-516e3aa7.woff                  32.32 kB
dist/assets/index-d58d460e.css                                       111.89 kB │ gzip:  57.46 kB
dist/assets/index-b72653c3.js                                      1,431.43 kB │ gzip: 407.52 kB

(!) Some chunks are larger than 500 kBs after minification. Consider:
- Using dynamic import() to code-split the application
- Use build.rollupOptions.output.manualChunks to improve chunking: https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-manualchunks
- Adjust chunk size limit for this warning via build.chunkSizeWarningLimit.
✓ built in 6.99s
```

npx lint-staged:

```
✔ Preparing lint-staged...
⚠ Running tasks for staged files...
  ❯ .lintstagedrc.json — 10 files
    ❯ *.+(jsx|ts|tsx) — 6 files
      ✔ npm run lint
      ✖ npm run build [FAILED]
    ✔ *.+(json|md) — 2 files
↓ Skipped because of errors from tasks.
✔ Reverting to original state because of errors...
✔ Cleaning up temporary files...

✖ npm run build:
Could not resolve entry module "src/config/axios-interceptor.ts/index.html".
error during build:
RollupError: Could not resolve entry module "src/config/axios-interceptor.ts/index.html".
    at error (file:///Users/m/Documents/vite-starter-typescript/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2245:30)
    at ModuleLoader.loadEntryModule (file:///Users/m/Documents/vite-starter-typescript/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24671:20)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

This is my file vite.config.ts

```
import path from 'node:path';

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      {
        find: /^~(.+)/,
        replacement: path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules/$1'),
      },
      {
        find: /^src(.+)/,
        replacement: path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/$1'),
      },
    ],
  },
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
  preview: {
    port: 3000,
  },
});
```

This is file index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
    />
    <link
      rel="manifest"
      href="/manifest.json"
    />
    <link
      rel="icon"
      href="/favicon.ico"
      type="image/x-icon"
    />
    <title>Devias Kit PRO</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!-- https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/6999 -->
    <script>
      const global = globalThis;
    </script>
    <script
      type="module"
      src="/src/main.tsx"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my file /src/main.tsx

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { Suspense } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { HelmetProvider } from 'react-helmet-async';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './redux/store';
import setupAxiosInterceptors from './config/axios-interceptor';

import { App } from 'src/app';

setupAxiosInterceptors(() => {});

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement);

root.render(
  <HelmetProvider>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Suspense>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <App />
        </Provider>
      </Suspense>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </HelmetProvider>
);
```

I don't know if I am missing something. What should I do to resolve this issue? Thank you a lot for helping me!